# Show Audio of Server Side Sound Card

Tags: javascript, php, apache, unix, audio-recording

Good Day,

I have a USB Audio device connected to my web server (RPi) running linux, apache2 and php.

I would like to display the sound level from the mic connected to the server via a webpage. I came across this html5 [example](https://codepen.io/travisholliday/pen/gyaJk) which uses the:

```
navigator.getUserMedia
```

However this is for a microphone on the client side.
Can someone advise how I could achieve a similar page that instead displays the 
level of the server side audio.

Thanks,

Comment: Best bet is to try and do this via the command line (e.g. using [amixer](http://linux.die.net/man/1/amixer) ) and then do `shell_exec('amixer <parameters>')` I highly doubt that PHP has a built-in way to get this information since it's not something one would often want to do on a webserver.

Comment: I do not believe amixer can be used to get current mic volume, however point taken a command like arecord or sox could be used to poll the volume which could then be used to feed the web graphic